# If statements with arrays in swift

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

I am having some trouble with my swift code. I want to make an endless game similar to the line zen, where a random node appears from the top. I used this code to help use the randomizer:

```
let randomWallNameIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))
    let wallNames = ["obsticle #1", "obsticle #2"]
    //can also be [1, 2,]

    if wallNames == "obsticle #1"{

       //insert code here
    }
```

Although, I'm having trouble using the if statement to tell whether a specific number was selected and I can spawn that certain node.

Can someone find the solution?

Comment: use wallName.contains("obsticle #1")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let randomWallNameIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))
let wallNames = ["obsticle #1", "obsticle #2"]
//can also be [1, 2,]
let wall = wallNames[randomWallNameIndex]
if wall == "obsticle #1"{

   //insert code here
}
```

Just add a variable that holds the string from the array at that index and use that variable in the if statement.